# InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'myListName[0]' of bean class

Tags: java, spring, proguard, thymeleaf, obfuscation

While running a Spring MVC web app using Thymeleaf and obfuscating with Proguard, I was running into the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: 
Invalid property 'listOfSomething[0]' of bean class ...
```

This worked fine before obfuscation, but breaks afterwards.

```
public class FormToSubmit {

    private List<MyType> listOfSomething;

    public List<MyType> getListOfSomething() {
        return listOfSomething;
    }

    public void setListOfSomething(List<MyType> listOfSomething) {
        this.listOfSomething = listOfSomething;
    }
}
```

I'm already keeping all the public property accessors during obfuscation during with the following proguard line:

```
-keep public class com.package.name.model.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the type parameter of the the list was being removed by proguard. Adding the following line to the proguard configuration resolved the issue.

```
-keepattributes Signature
```